# Measure of the range of a function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Suppose that given a function $G:\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^d$, the goal is to compute or bound the probability measure of its range. Explicitly, I need to compute
$$\int_{G(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)}\mathrm{d}\mu,$$
where $\mu$ is a probability measure, say Gaussian, that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathrm{d}\mu=1$. The function satisfies the linearity that $G(x,\lambda y)=\lambda G(x,y)$ where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

I would guess the measure depends on the dimensions $m,n,d$. Is there anything to which I can refer to approach this problem? Any suggestions would be appreciated.